# best way to install gnome on headless ubuntu server

Tags: 12.04, server, gnome

I installed a new headless server with 12.04 and ssh. Now users want to ssh in and use gnome-terminal, gedit, etc....  Rather than install each of these separately, is there a parent package that would install most/all of the g* apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ubuntu-desktop package should provide everything you need to run a gui.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop gnome
```